# Visual Studio:How to show a link after installation had finished?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

Within an installer build using Visual Studio 2008 I like to show a link to a website at the end of the installation that the user can click to open the URL inside the standard browser.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Hyperlink control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407936(VS.85).aspx) is only supported in Windows Installer 5.0 (i.e. Windows 7, Server 2008 R2)

To do this with older versions of Windows Installer, you'll need to create a CustomAction that launches the website, and then tie the execution of the CustomAction to a button, another common use is to create a checkbox saying "Launch blah blah..." and then tie a CustomAction to the 'Finish' button which executes based on the value of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a custom dialog window is what you need. See here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/vsSetupCustomDialogs.aspx